# Excel 2016 VBA: Set Source Data for a Chart to a Named Table

Tags: vba, excel

The title is pretty self-explanatory.

I have a named table, `Table_Unit_2_Data`, which I would like to set as the source data for a chart that will be created using VBA.

During the recording of a macro I selected the entirety of the table, and inserted a chart. This is the code that I got (Build is the name of the Sheet):

```
Sub Test()
    Range("Table_Unit_2_Data[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:= Range("Build!$Y$1:$AD$2")
End Sub
```

Well, for one thing, as you can see, a specific $A$1 range is passed into the SetSoureData. This will not work because the range of `Table_Unit_2_Data` will change.

I attempted this:

```
With Sheet2.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers)
    .Chart.SetSourceData (Sheet2.Range("Table_Unit_2_Data[#All]"))
End With
```

But then I get the error "Object Required".

I can't seem to phrase my search queries in such a way as to find relevant answers to this specific question on the internet so I apologize for asking what is likely a redundant question. If someone could help me with this problem I would be greatly appreciative and if anyone has a good article or source online for information regarding the nuances of chart creation within VBA that would also be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: When you enclose an argument within brackets, you force the argument to be passed by value.  So here an array of values is passed to SetSourceData instead of a range object.  Therefore, remove the brackets from your argument -->  `.Chart.SetSourceData Sheet2.Range("Table_Unit_2_Data[#All]")`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Domenic said (which is correct + would cause the "Object Required" error), your code doesn't make it clear what "Sheet2" is, except that it's the [codename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel) of some sheet. From the recorded macro, I can infer that the actual table is on a sheet called "Build", so another possibility to consider is that Sheet2 isn't actually the codename of Sheets("Build"). Again, I can't actually tell from the code provided.

While I do like using sheet codenames, I'd strongly recommend against using them if you're not going to make the names descriptive.

FWIW,  there's another way to reference table ranges that's a little more flexible, especially if you're going to be referring to the table elsewhere in the code. Just make a ListObject variable:

```
Dim UnitTable2 As ListObject
Set UnitTable2 = Sheets("Build").ListObjects("Table_Unit_2_Data")
```

And you'll be able to reference any part of the table really easily:

```
Dim rng As Range
'Reference the whole table, including headers:
Set rng = UnitTable2.Range
'Reference just the table data (no headers):
Set rng = UnitTable2.DataBodyRange
'Reference just the data in a single column:
Set rng = UnitTable2.ListColumns("Col1").DataBodyRange
'Reference the headers only
Set rng = UnitTable2.HeaderRowRange
```